# AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'app'

Tags: python, appium, bdd, appium-android

Hello I did not found answer for similar problem so I add new topic.
I have problem with bdd + appium using a page object model. When I run my script I have issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mimy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 1329, in run
    match.run(runner.context)
  File "/home/mimy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/behave/matchers.py", line 98, in run
    self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "features/steps/allow_to_app_steps.py", line 6, in tap_allow_when_using_app
    context.app.launch_page.tap_allow_button()
  File "/home/mimy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 321, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(msg)
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'app'
```

My environment.py file looks like this:

```
from appium import webdriver
from app.application import Application


def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    desired_capabilities = {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "platformVersion": "10",
        "deviceName": "Pixel 2 XL",
        "appPackage": "com.xxx.xxx",
        "appActivity": ".ui.MainActivity",
        "automationName": "UiAutomator2"

    }

    context.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
    context.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    context.app = Application(context.driver)


def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.driver.quit()
```

My steps file looks like this:

```
from behave import given, when, then, step


@given('I click on the "Allow only while using the app" button')
def tap_allow_when_using_app(context):
    context.app.launch_page.tap_allow_button()



@when('I click on the "Allow" button')
def tap_allow(context):
    context.app.launch_page.tap_allow()
```

My pages file for my page object model looks like:

```
###LunchPage###

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pages.base_page import Page


class LaunchPage(Page):
    dialog_title = (By.XPATH, "//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Allow QSpot to access this device')]")
    allow_only_while_using_the_app = (By.XPATH, "//android.widget.Button[@text='Allow only while using the app']")
    allow = (By.XPATH, "//android.widget.Button[@text='Allow']")

    def tap_allow_button(self):
        self.click(*self.allow_only_while_using_the_app)

    def tap_allow(self):
        self.click(*self.allow)

###BasePage###
class Page:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def find_element(self, *locator):
        return self.driver.find_element(*locator)

    def click(self, *locator):
        e = self.find_element(*locator)
        e.click()
```

And class Application

```
from pages.launch_page import LaunchPage


class Application:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.launch_page = LaunchPage(driver)
```

As I now this issue may be related with "driver was not starting" but I am not able to fix it.
Many thanks for help!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `before_scenario` is run prior to any call to `tap_allow_when_using_app`?

Comment: You mean that `before_scenario` may be not run first? Hm.... at the moment I am not sure. @Random have you got more tips? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying. I'm not at all familiar with the libraries you're using so I personally can't give any specific tips, other than that obvious one. I also recommend using a debugger to step through the code, if possible, if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I missed up names in architecture names.
So after changing from "enviroment" to "environment" (missing N).
it became alive.

Comment: In general please avoid posting answers that boil down to "I made a typo". This is too specific to your case and does not help other users. Think about it: you could post such answers to most of the questions on this site...